# Click event produces different transition delays, despite equal values

Tags: reactjs, css, css-transitions

I am creating a simple Dropdown menu in React. The initial event of the drop down works as expected. However, when retracting the dropdown there is a noticeable delay in the transition despite equal default values.

The CSS transition properties are identical so I am not sure why there is a delay. I have also set the transition delay value of both explicitly to 0, to be sure.

here is the component

```
class DrawerLink extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { collapse: false };
    this.handleLinkToggle = this.handleLinkToggle.bind(this);
  }

  handleLinkToggle(e) {
    this.setState({ collapse: !this.state.collapse });
  }

  render() {
    const { collapse } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="DrawerLinkContainer">
        <div onClick={this.handleLinkToggle}>
          <div className="image-container">
            <img src="../public/images/user.jpeg" />
          </div>
          <p>Steave Jobs</p>
        </div>
        <div
          className={
            collapse ? "sub-menu-container collapse" : "sub-menu-container"
          }
        >
          <p>First Sub Menu</p>
          <p>Second Sub Menu</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the CSS:

```
.sub-menu-container {
  padding-left: 40px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s linear 0s;
  &.collapse {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 1s linear 0s;
  }
  p {
    padding: 7px 35px 7px 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have set `max-height` to 500px and your content is only about 60px, the first transition is still executing causing what seems like a delay. I.E increasing to a "max height" of 500px.

You can see better if you set a background colour on the sub container and set the height equal to the max height in the `collapse` class. Something like:

```
.sub-menu-container {
    padding-left: 40px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1s linear 0s;
    background: red;
    &.collapse {
        max-height: 0px;
    }
    p {
        padding: 7px 35px 7px 15px;
    }
}
```

The real solution is to use an animation library because transitions have issues (they just don't work) when element are removed from the DOM by React.

If you need a solution to your example, you need to know the height of the sub container and use that as a max height. It's not very dynamic though.

Comment: Interesting, I guess I can pass down the number of submenu items as props and calculate 30px for each

Comment: Yes, that would mean moving the height styling to javascript. The library I was talking about is https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group.
If I remember collectly, its quite a steep learning curve but its is better than mixing style between JS and CSS